# new thread not showing the frame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to establish a network connection and the details are in a JFrame. When user clicks a button, it should start the new thread and should show the wait message to the user until, the main thread establish a network connection. I wrote this code

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
     Thread ref = new Thread(new Test());//Create a new thread
     ref.start();
      new AIDRTConnManager().createConnection(ipAddress, portAddress);//main thread
      }



//This is my Thread Class
    public class Test implements Runnable{
    JDialog waitDialog;
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel waitLabel;
    JFrame frame;


    public void run(){
        frame = new JFrame();
         waitDialog = new JDialog( frame,AIRDT.toolName, true );
         waitDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation( JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE );  
         JLabel waitLabel = new JLabel( "Trying to Connect to PleaseWait...",ErrorDialog.icon,SwingConstants.CENTER ); 
            panel1.add( waitLabel ); 
            waitDialog.add( panel1 );  
            waitDialog.setSize( 100, 40 ); 
            waitDialog.setBounds( 500,300, 300, 80 ); 
        waitDialog.setVisible( true ); 
    }
}
```

But when I click the button, the Jdialog shows the empty frame, without the wait message (JLable) and once I done with the network connection, this wait message shows properly.

Where I am going wrong? Is this a Swing Issue (Or) Thread Issue?

Could you please help me to show a wait message until the completion of back end activity?

Comment: Funny that you call `waitDialog.setSize( 100, 40 ); 
            waitDialog.setBounds( 500,300, 300, 80 ); ` `setBounds` is a shortcut for calling setLocation() and setSize() at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up your threads here - all operations that interact with the UI, such as creating a new frame, must occur on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), or the "main" thread as you call it. Background tasks should be performed on a different thread.

Basically you have it backwards - you should perform the background work in the new thread, and create the new frame in the main thread, which is the opposite way to how you have it now.

Comment: +1 indeed he got it all reversed. The wait dialog should be initiated in the actionPerformed while the connection should be done in a New Thread. Just to clarify it all, what is usually referred as the "Main Thread" is the Thread in which the `main(String[] args)` method is invoked at the starup of the JVM. It is often mixed with the EDT because many users start the UI within the "Main Thread" while it should actually be done with a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to do this in the EDT.

Comment: @ajshort Thanks for your detailed explanation. It resolved my issue partially. I did my background work in the new thread and it created the network connection too. Meanwhile I set waitDialog.setVisible( true ); in my main Thread. But after setting this my main thread is not resuming at all. What happends in waitDialog.setVisible(true);? It shows the wait dialog. But after that Nothing works. I added a condition to check whether my background work got done. If so,I am trying to hide the Waitdialog.But this condition itself not running. waitDialog.setVisible(true) freeze the main thread.Pl Help

Comment: Rather than adding a condition, you should add a callback from the thread you create back to your main thread to notify it when the work is done. There's a "SwingWorker" class, which is designed for exactly what you are trying to do. It will run a task in the background, and then call a `done` method on the EDT when it completes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html for a really good overview.

Comment: @ajshort I done with this application and wanted to create a jar. I referenced some images like this Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/images/icon.gif")); But the jar is not executing at all. How can I include the images into the jar?

Answer (score 3):

The code under the `actionPerformed` executes under the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), not on the main thread as you say in the comment.

This means that as long as the connection thing happens, the EDT is blocked, so it doesn't have to chance to process some other UI stuff like displaying your `JDialog`.

Also, not related to the issue, but please note that you create a `JFrame` that is never displayed and that is the parent of your `JDialog`.